# Hibernate: store facial embeddings in 128 columns

Tags: java, hibernate, face-recognition

How to better store facial embeddings in a database using Hibernate?

I have 128 float values which **MUST** be stored in different columns (I need this to create procedures on them later).

How should look annotated hibernate POJO model for this? Should I create 128 fields in POJO ? Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1 : @ElementCollection***

It's an easy solution. But not the most efficient (depending on your usage) :

```
@ElementCollection
@OrderColumn("index")
private List<Float> facialEmbeddings;
```

@ElementCollection will store the elements in another table.

@OrderColumn("index") use the column "index" that contains integer values of the positions of the elements 0, 1, 2, etc.

**Solution 2 : New @Entity with @ManyToOne**

Create an new @Entity containing the float value. and use a bidirectionnal @ManyToOne.
This solution can be more perfomant if you found yourself usualy editing the facialEmbeddings list.

You can found more informations about the performance problem in this link : https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-elementcollection/